# Running Apache Ignite Cluster on Pivotal Cloud Foundry environment

Tags: spring-boot, ignite, cloud-foundry

I am trying to build a Apache Ignite Cluster on Pivotal Cloud Foundry environment as follows.

1. Created a Spring-Boot app that starts a new Ignite node, Deployed it on on Cloud Foundry ( ex. Ignite-Node1)
2. Created another Spring-Boot app which will also starts a new Ignite node, Deployed it on on Cloud Foundry ( ex. Ignite-Node2)

Now, even though both the apps are running in a same CloudFoundry Env, they are not forming the Ignite Cluster as they are not able to discover each other.

Apache Ignite documentation provides examle configuration details for AWS, Google cloud , however there are no examples for Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

Can somebody provide me with an example configuration on how to get the Ignite Cluster running on Cloud Foundry environment.

- Srini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container-to-container (app-to-app) networking is not supported on Pivotal Cloud Foundry, [although it is possible to enable](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/container-networking-for-pcf/blob/master/pcf_with_netman.md).

By default all communications must be made 'via the front door' through Cloud Foundry's router, either via HTTP or on a TCP port. One cannot choose which instance of an application to hit. This is due to change with the Container Networking initiative, the [progress of which you can check on Pivotal Tracker](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/1498342). There is a [detailed design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HDS89TJKD7ACG6cqQHph5BdNSKLt8jvo6sPGBZ5DmsM/edit#heading=h.2vczndly0dxu) which is publicly available.

An alternative approach which is more appropriate for data services is to [deploy them using BOSH](http://mariash.github.io/learn-bosh/). As a PCF user, you may wish to consider [creating a PCF Tile](https://docs.pivotal.io/partners/creating.html) for Apache Ignite.

My company has been helping Hazelcast create a PCF Tile that will create dedicated-VM clusters on-demand. Perhaps you could consider making use of Hazelcast instead?

Comment: Pivotal Cloud Foundry has had the ability to enable container to container networking for a while now.  It is a specific option that you need to enable and is disabled by default.  Pivotal does not recommend using it unless *all* of the applications you are running are considered "trusted".  You would never want to run untrusted applications in this configuration.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise. Which version was that introduced in, and is configuration documented? Will update my answer when I get back to my machine.

Comment: I can't recall, exactly when it was added but I looked at a lab running PCF 1.6 and it's in there.  It's under the ERT Tile -> Security Config.  The setting is "Enable cross-container traffic".